# document.scrollTop value needed in Ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need to get the scrollTop position in my Ionic 2 page, but it is just not working.

The same code is working in normal html page but it always returns `0` in IONIC.

See code below, which is working:

```js
$("body").click(function(){
    var scrollPost = $(document).scrollTop();
    alert(scrollPost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>
test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>
<div class="test">Thats a test</div>
```

I have installed jQuery in my Ionic project and it is working but particularly this `$(document).scrollTop();` function is not working, every time it is giving me `0`.

I have done a lot of work in my app on context menu, and if now I have to change it to something else, it will be a huge pain for me. How can I get the `scrollTop` value?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a more 'Angular' way, without jQuery and it doesn't requre much change.

Define a Viewchild in your document (An element you want to scroll to).

```
<div #topScroll></div>
```

and then in your Page controller define:

```
  export class Page {

  @ViewChild(Content) topScroll: Content;

      private scrollToTop() {
          this.topScroll.scrollToTop(500);
      }
  }
```

This will scroll to the top of the element.

Comment: there will be n number of div's on my html page, on each div i add this class according to you and when i right to show the contextmenu, its css `top` should be `this.topScroll.scrollToTop(500);` as per you ?

Comment: like the above running jsfiddle, can you please stackblitz your code if possible ?  it will be much helpful

Comment: i dont want to scroll to top of my page, i want the px value when clicked

Comment: This code replaces that, no need for pxs. To whichever element you are trying to scroll, just add a selector to that element and use this code. If it's a bunch of random paragraphs, just add a div around them and scroll to that div, no need to add class to all elements, just the one you want to scroll to.

Comment: This is giving error, can you make stackblitz please